# Error when service provider imports metadata from wso2IS 5.3.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are working with a service provider and they are having issues importing the metadata we exported from wso2. The error that they are seeing trying to import the metadata that was exported from wso2.

"Unexpected error during metadata import, likely caused by invalid XML: Invalid XML - errors: [error: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'AttributeService@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' instead of 'NameIDFormat@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' here in element AttributeAuthorityDescriptor@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata, error: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'AttributeService@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' instead of 'NameIDFormat@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' here in element AttributeAuthorityDescriptor@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata, error: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'AttributeService@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata' before the end of the content in element AttributeAuthorityDescriptor@urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata

They are saying it is a configuration problem on our end but we many other working Service providers.

Edit adding metadata:
https://idp-dev.westga.edu/authenticationendpoint/idp-dev-metadata.xml

Comment: Please add the metadata file here to see what is the error you are getting.

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: Reading the error message you have posted, seems to be your service provider expects AttributeAuthorityDescriptor and AttributeService in the metadata which is not advertised in the metadata file.

Comment: wso2 does not output that in our metadata is there something we need to configure

Comment: Issue resolved but still would like more info if anyone has it. Vendor eventually agreed to manually config on their end and issue was resolved their side did not require we provide anything that was not already in our metadata when manually configured. Supposedly for reference they were using ping federate.